# Java Sandboxing Security Policy

Tags: java, stack-overflow, sandbox

I am following this [tutorial, Sandboxing plugins in Java](https://blog.jayway.com/2014/06/13/sandboxing-plugins-in-java/) on how to achieve sandboxing when plugins are used.

This is my main class where I load the class from the Jar file and run the interface function:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.Policy;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Policy.setPolicy(new SandboxSecurityPolicy());
        System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());


        try {
            File file = new File("JarDummy.jar");
            URL urlJar = file.toURI().toURL();

            ClassLoader pluginLoader = new PluginClassLoader(urlJar);

            Class<?> pluginClass = pluginLoader.loadClass("ZEngine");
            IEngine plugin = (IEngine) pluginClass.newInstance();

            plugin.build("file.txt");

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

This is my interface:

```
public interface IEngine {

    void build(String filename);
}
```

This is my plugin class loader:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class PluginClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    public PluginClassLoader(URL jarFileUrl) {
        super(new URL[] {jarFileUrl});
    }
}
```

And this is my policy where different permissions are given if the class is loaded from the plugin:

```
import sun.plugin.security.PluginClassLoader;
import java.security.AllPermission;
import java.security.PermissionCollection;
import java.security.Permissions;
import java.security.Policy;
import java.security.ProtectionDomain;

public class SandboxSecurityPolicy extends Policy {

    @Override
    public PermissionCollection getPermissions(ProtectionDomain domain) {
        if (isPlugin(domain)) {
            return pluginPermissions();
        }
        else {
            return applicationPermissions();
        }
    }

    private boolean isPlugin(ProtectionDomain domain) {
        return domain.getClassLoader() instanceof PluginClassLoader;
    }

    private PermissionCollection pluginPermissions() {
        Permissions permissions = new Permissions(); // No permissions
        return permissions;
    }

    private PermissionCollection applicationPermissions() {
        Permissions permissions = new Permissions();
        permissions.add(new AllPermission());
        return permissions;
    }
}
```

When I run the main class and code executes the `plugin.build()`, I am getting a stackoverflow exception with the following trace:

```
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "!errorOutstanding" with message transform method call failed at JPLISAgent.c line: 844
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.updatePositions(UTF_8.java:77)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8.access$200(UTF_8.java:57)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeArrayLoop(UTF_8.java:636)
    at sun.nio.cs.UTF_8$Encoder.encodeLoop(UTF_8.java:691)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:579)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:271)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:129)
    at java.io.PrintStream.write(PrintStream.java:526)
    at java.io.PrintStream.print(PrintStream.java:669)
    at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:806)
    at SandboxSecurityPolicy.getPermissions(SandboxSecurityPolicy.java:12)
    at java.security.Policy.implies(Policy.java:721)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain.implies(ProtectionDomain.java:285)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:450)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPackageAccess(SecurityManager.java:1564)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:318)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at SandboxSecurityPolicy.isPlugin(SandboxSecurityPolicy.java:23)
    at SandboxSecurityPolicy.getPermissions(SandboxSecurityPolicy.java:13)
```

I am not sure why that `instanceOf` is creating a recursion leading to this overflow. I appreciate your help. Thanks!

UPDATE: I ran the same code on a different machine, it worked fine. It seems like a JDK bug.

Comment: I know this was a long time ago, but I'm looking at exactly the same tutorial. Do you happen to know which versions of the JVM you were seeing this behavior in? I'm seeing the StackOverflowError in a couple versions of Java8, as well as in Java11.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I am sorry this was a long time ago and can't recall the java version used at the time. I should've mentioned it in the issue. Good luck!